# Fail to build makefile in eclipse cdt

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I keep getting error

```
make: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.
```

I am sure my makefile works perfectly, because I did run it on the terminal and everything fine. But when I try to import everything into eclispe by create an Empty Makefile Project, I couldn't compile the program. So did I miss something in eclipse configuration ?

Anyway, this is my makefile, please take a look, and correct me. Thanks

```
CC = g++
prog: legrec.o game.o board.o piece.o 
    $(CC) legrec.o game.o board.o piece.o -Wall -Werror -pedantic -o legrec
legrec.o: legrec.cpp game.h
    $(CC) -Wall -Werror -pedantic -c legrec.cpp
game.o: game.cpp game.h board.h piece.h move.h player.h
    $(CC) -Wall -Werror -pedantic -c game.cpp
board.o: board.cpp board.h piece.h move.h player.h
    $(CC) -Wall -Werror -pedantic -c board.cpp
piece.o: piece.cpp piece.h board.h move.h player.h
    $(CC) -Wall -Werror -pedantic -c piece.cpp
```

EDIT: Thanks for all replies, I did change the first line into all:legrec, and the previous error message was gone, however another errors came out

```
     cc   legrec.o   -o legrec
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "game::game()", referenced from:
         _main in legrec.o
    "game::printMenu()", referenced from:
         _main in legrec.o
    "game::printBoard()", referenced from:
         _main in legrec.o
    "game::nextMove()", referenced from:
         _main in legrec.o
    "game::ended()", referenced from:
         _main in legrec.o
    "game::printWinner()", referenced from:
         _main in legrec.o
    "game::~game()", referenced from:
         _main in legrec.o
    "std::terminate()", referenced from:
         _main in legrec.o
    "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
         __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in legrec.o
    "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
         ___tcf_0 in legrec.o
    "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
         Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in legrec.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
 make: *** [legrec] Error 1
```

I just don't understand why running same platform but the program performs differently. Before I was run on the terminal and edit on there that seems very well, but after porting into Eclipse, it drives me insance with the weird errors.

Comment: You didn't read my answer completely. The 'prog' target must be renamed too.

Answer (score 1):

Your very first rule is not really good.

You could rename it to `all` and it would "work". But a better approach would be:

```
all: legrec

legrec: legrec.o game.o board.o piece.o 
    $(CC) legrec.o game.o board.o piece.o -Wall -Werror -pedantic -o legrec
```

i.e. the rule name should match the output produced.

If you type just `make` on the command line, the very first rule encountered is run (that's why it works for you). I'm guessing your IDE is running `make all`, and you haven't defined such a rule.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert, but I'll try to help.
Rename the maketarget `prog` to `legrec"`
Try adding the following lines

`.PHONY: all clean

all: legrec`

Also your makefile doesn't have clean target. For that looking at your make file I suggest adding

```
clean:
    @rm *.o legrec
```

Comment: Didn't realize your end artefact was named "legrec". You could change the target name from prog to legrec as suggested by @Mat here.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the makefile in a number of ways to reduce duplication.

`make` knows how to turn a cpp file into an object file so you dont need to tell it.  Just define the compiler and the options to use: I have added CPPFLAGS.

`make` will build the first target it finds in the makefile - in this case 'legrec'. The $@ in the LD (link) command refers to `legrec`. The $^ refers to the prerequisites (ie the list of objects)

Here is my version:

```
CC = g++
CPPFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -pedantic
LDFLAGS =

legrec: legrec.o game.o board.o piece.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@

legrec.o: game.h
game.o:   board.h piece.h move.h player.h game.h
board.o:  board.h piece.h move.h player.h
piece.o:  board.h piece.h move.h player.h

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @rm -f *.o legrec
```

Note that you can add -g or -O etc to the CPPFLAGS line. By the way, there are many more warnings that the compiler can give you than are produced by -Wall.   For C, I normally use:

```
-Wall \
-Wextra \
-Wshadow \
-Wstrict-prototypes \
-Wmissing-prototypes \
-Wundef \
-Wunreachable-code \
-Wunused \
-Wcast-qual
```